# Nginx Load Balancing Hash Partial Uri

Tags: nginx, hash, uri, load-balancing

Can NGINX load balancing using just partial URI to hash?

For example:

One request to:

```
abc.test.com/1.jpg
```

hash just "abc".

For a request to:

```
def.test.com/index.html
```

hash just "def".

Comment: what do you exactly need? to have 2 different application, each sits on its own subdomain?

Comment: @mikhailov We have several function parts in different subdomains, and we have two servers now. We want to balance load to these 2 servers and each one just take a few of function parts. But for one function, if we add more subdomains, it still go to a same server.

Comment: yes, take a look: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html